# Jquery favorites star button

Tags: php, jquery

I'm new with jquery and I have some problems with this code. I'm trying to make work a favorite button (in this case a star image): in my website, each item (cd) has a favorite button and, if you click on it (and it is not colored), the item is inserted in the favorite items table and the button becomes colored (yellow); if you click on the button and it is already colored (so this means it's a favorite), the item is removed from the table and the button returns with no color.
I have two problems with this code:

1. Using `$(".star")` it obvoiusly makes all stars (even other items' stars) become yellow, instead I want only the star I've clicked on to become yellow;
2. How can I make the changes persistent? In other words, I would like that if an item is added to favorites, its star keeps being yellow in the future, unless I obviously click another time on that.

```js
$(".star").on('click',function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'homepage/homepage_query.php',
    data: {ins:true, title:$("#right_title").text()},     
    datatype:'json',
    success: function(json){
      if(json == 0){  //it has been removed from favorites
        $(".star").css({"background-color":"initial"});
      }else{    //it has been added to favorites
        $(".star").css({"background-color":"#ffdb4d"});
      }
    },
    error: function(e){
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
if(isset($_GET["ins"]) && isset($_GET["title"])){  
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=music", "user", "pwd");
        $username = $_SESSION["name"];
        $us = $db->quote($username);
        $titolo = $_GET["title"];
        $ti = $db->quote($titolo);
        $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE username=$us AND titolo=$ti");
        $res = $rows->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($res){   
            $rows = $db->query("DELETE FROM favorites WHERE username=$us AND titolo=$ti");
            $res = $rows->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            var_dump($res);
            echo 0;
        }else{     
            $db->query("INSERT INTO favorites VALUES ($us, $ti)");
            echo json_encode($res);
        }
    }
```

```html
<img class="star" src="img/stella.png"/> <!--the star I click on-->
```

Comment: can you `console.log(json)` in success and see what coming there ? Let me know

Comment: It shows me this: []

Comment: But at first I've not inserted any row in the favorites table, I was thinking of adding values trough the website

Comment: That means your `if` condition goes to `else` because it not returning `0` - Is your query successful updating in the database ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes, both insert and delete queries work correctly on updating the database

Comment: In your `PHP` file can you add `var_dump($res)` in your if condition and see what returned from the database ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping so do I have to write that line in my PHP file? Because I do not have $res in PHP. Sorry but I'm new to these languages so I have some difficulties

Comment: Yes in your PHP file add `var_dump($res)` and see what are the results when you run the query via `ajax`

Comment: I've updated my code, please check if it's written correctly, because it shows me nothing (but shoud I see in the browser console, right?)

Comment: You `PHP` need some fixing that why you are getting the right data back from your ajax success. You need to debug your PHP code to make sure if sending the back data which either `0` or else json data of insert.

Comment: I've checked error.log file but I have no errors... but I was thinking the problem was in jquery, because all queries work correctly on the database, the two problems I have are about the website and what I see in it

Answer (score -1):

Change your code with below to check/uncheck perticular star.

```
$(".star").on('click',function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url:'homepage/homepage_query.php',
    data: {ins:true, title:$("#right_title").text()},     
    success: function(resp){
            var msg = resp.toString();
        if(msg == 'removed'){  //it has been removed from favorites
            $this.css({"background-color":"initial"});
        }else{    //it has been added to favorites
            $this.css({"background-color":"#ffdb4d"});
        }
    },
    error: function(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    }
  });
});
```

==================================================

```
if(isset($_GET["ins"]) && isset($_GET["title"])){  
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=music", "user", "pwd");
    $username = $_SESSION["name"];
    $us = $db->quote($username);
    $titolo = $_GET["title"];
    $ti = $db->quote($titolo);
    $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE username=$us AND titolo=$ti");
    $res = $rows->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($res){   
        $rows = $db->query("DELETE FROM favorites WHERE username=$us AND titolo=$ti");
        $res = $rows->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo "removed";exit();
    }else{     
        $db->query("INSERT INTO favorites VALUES ($us, $ti)");
        echo "added";exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Titania Remove datatype:'json'  from AJAX if you are using response for only check type.

Comment: Thanks, but as before, I see no changes in the result...

Comment: What you got in response in success event?

Comment: But with console.log(json)? I got: added (if I add a favorite)

Comment: @Titania Please check edited ans. toString methos. If possible provide URL